# How to minimise light propagation time in a spherical mirror?

Tags: geometry, calculus-of-variations

I have attached a picture of a light ray bouncing off a spherical mirror. I wish to show that the travel time of the ray is minimised for $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$. This can be argued geometrically by showing that side EB is greater than side CB, but I was looking for a more analytic approach, namely finding the travel time in terms of theta and differentiating to find the minimum. My main difficulty is actually finding an explicit expression for side EB in terms of R and $\theta$. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: I might be wrong, but why is the ray reflecting like that. If C is the centre of the circle then any ray passing through C always remains on the same line segment

Comment: Perhaps you wanted an elliptical mirror with foci C and B?

Comment: The fact that any ray passing through C remains on that line segment is actually what I’m trying to prove. I’m considering an arbitrary path that the light ray takes and by Fermat’s Principle of Least time, I will find the path the light will actually take (which should be for $\theta = 0$

Comment: How is $\theta=\pi$ even possible?

Comment: $$AB^2=AC^2+BC^2+2 AC\cdot BC\,\cos\theta.$$

Comment: I suppose OP should close the circle in the picture. For shown configuration $\theta=\pi$ is best scenario.